Algorithm for $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)x^n\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1-kx}{1+kx}$

Let $a(n)$ be A208832. Here
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)x^n\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1-kx}{1+kx}.
$$
Start with vector $\nu$ of fixed length $m$ with elements $\nu_i = 1$ (that is, $\nu = \{1, 1, \dotsc, 1\}$), reserve $t$ as an empty vector of fixed length $m$, set $t:=\nu$ and for $i$ from $1$ to $m-1$, for $j$ from $1$ to $m-i$ consecutively apply
$$
\nu_{j+1} := i\nu_j + \nu_{j+1}, \\
\nu_{j} := i\nu_j + \nu_{j+1}.
$$
We also need to apply $t_{i+1} = \nu_1$ (after ending each cycle for $j$).

I conjecture that after the whole transform we have
$$
t_n = a(n).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to generate $t$:
upto1(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, 1); v2 = v1; for(i=1, n-1, for(j=1, n-i, v1[j+1] += i*v1[j]; v1[j] = i*v1[j] + v1[j+1]); v2[i+1] = v1[1]); v2

In addition, this question can be rephrased as follows:

Let
$$
R(n, q) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } n = 0 \\
R(n-1, q+1) + 2\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q} n^{q-j+1}R(n-1,j) & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I conjecture that
$$
R(n,0)=a(n+1).
$$
Is there a way to prove it?
